# Java: How to replace consecutive characters with a single character?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

How can I replace consecutive characters with a single character in java?

```
String fileContent = "def  mnop.UVW";
String oldDelimiters = " .";
String newDelimiter = "!";
for (int i = 0; i < oldDelimiters.length(); i++){
    Character character = oldDelimiters.charAt(i);
    fileContent = fileContent.replace(String.valueOf(character), newDelimiter);
}
```

Current output: `def!!mnop!UVW`

Desired output: `def!mnop!UVW`

Notice the two spaces are replaced with two exclamation marks. How can I replace consecutive delimiters with one delimiter?

Comment: `oldDelimiters` have two characters.

Comment: @SudhirOjha That is correct. That is why I looped over oldDelimiters.

Comment: Try a regex with a character class quantified one to many; for example: `String result = text.replaceAll("[ .]+", "!");`.

Comment: @user85421 Yeah I fixed the single quote. I will update to reflect.

Comment: @oriberu How can I add the delimiter variable in the regex? I tried `fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll("[oldDelimiter]+", newDelimiter);` but it didn't work.

Comment: @ChrisSmith Depends on your `oldDelimiter` string; if it contains a character (or several single characters) use something like `"[" + oldDelimiter + "]+"` for the expression part; if it is a single string, use something like `"(?:" + oldDelimiter + ")+"`. Sorry for the edits.

Comment: @oriberu `"[" + oldDelimiter + "]+"` worked. I need to learn regex. Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisSmith I'm all for solving things algorithmically, but there are scenarios where RE are very handy to get a quick solution.

Comment: @ChrisSmith What should be the output for `abc .df`? Is it `abc!!df` or `abc!df`? Notice that your title says _How to replace consecutive characters with a single character_ , so it appears that double consecutive `!` is valid in this case.

Comment: @vivek_23 In the case you specified, the desired output is abc!!df. Essentially, replace each old delimiter `" ."` with and the new delimiter `"!"`. The new delimiter can be repeated as long as it is not due to consecutive old delimiters(like the two spaces in my example). Let me know if I did not explain it well.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to match consecutive characters from the old delimiter, a regex solution doesn't seem to be feasible here. You can instead match char by char if it belongs to one of the old delimiter chars and then set it with the new one as shown below.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileContent = "def  mnop.UVW";
        String oldDelimiters = " .";

        // add all old delimiters in a set for fast checks
        Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
        for(int i=0;i<oldDelimiters.length();++i) set.add(oldDelimiters.charAt(i));

        /* 
           match all consecutive chars at once, check if it belongs to an old delimiter 
           and replace it with the new one
        */

        String newDelimiter = "!";
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder("");
        for(int i=0;i<fileContent.length();++i){
            if(set.contains(fileContent.charAt(i))){
                while(i + 1 < fileContent.length() && fileContent.charAt(i) == fileContent.charAt(i+1)) i++;
                res.append(newDelimiter);
            }else{
                res.append(fileContent.charAt(i));        
            }
        }

        System.out.println(res.toString());
    }
}
```

**Demo:** https://onlinegdb.com/r1BC6qKP8

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difficulty to using a regex for this, is to create an expression from your `oldDelimiters` string. For example:

```java
String oldDelimiters = " .";
String expression = "\\" + String.join("+|\\", oldDelimiters.split("")) + "+";
String text = "def  mnop.UVW;abc .df";
String result = text.replaceAll(expression, "!");
```

*(Edit: since characters in the expression are now escaped anyway, I removed the character classes and edited the following text to reflect that change.)*

Where the generated expression looks like `\ +|\.+`, i.e. each character is quantified and constitutes one alternative of the expression. The engine will match and replace one alternative at a time if it can be matched. `result` now contains:

```
def!mnop!UVW;abc!!df
```

Not sure how backwards compatible this is due to `split()` behaviour in previous versions of Java (producing a leading space in splitting on the empty string), but with current versions this should be fine.

*Edit: As it is, this breaks if the delimiting characters contain digits or characters representing unescaped regex tokens (i.e. `1`, `b`, etc.).*

Comment: It might be better to escape the characters.  That way it would work even if oldDelimiters where included '^','\' or ']'

Comment: @Taemyr That's fair, and if I had known of a straightforward way to do that in Java, I would have included it. Since those characters were not part of the question, I omitted that from the demonstration.

Comment: @Taemyr Omg, I didn't see the wood for the trees. I was thinking about pattern quote functions but I could have just added backslashes. ^^; See my edit. Thanks for the inquiry.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = s.replaceAll("([ \\.])[ \\.]+", "$1");
```

Or if only several *same* delimiters have to be replaced:

```
s = s.replaceAll("([ \\.])\\1+", "$1");
```

- `[....]` is a group of alternative characters
- First `(...)` is group 1, `$1`
- `\\1` is the text of the first group

Answer (score 1):

While not using regex, I thought a solution with `StreamS` was needed, because everyone loves streams:

```
private static class StatefulFilter implements Predicate<String> {
    private final String needle;
    private String last = null;

    public StatefulFilter(String needle) {
        this.needle = needle;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(String value) {
        boolean duplicate = last != null && last.equals(value) && value.equals(needle);
        last = value;
        return !duplicate;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(
        "def  mnop.UVW"
        .codePoints()
        .sequential()
        .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))
        .filter(new StatefulFilter(" "))
        .map(x -> x.equals(" ") ? "!" : x)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(""))
    );
}
```

Runnable example: https://onlinegdb.com/BkY0R2twU

**Explanation:**

Theoretically, you aren't really supposed to have a stateful filter, but technically, as long as the stream is not parallelized, it works fine:

`.codePoints()` - splits the `String` into a `Stream`

`.sequential()` - since we care about the order of characters, our `Stream` may not be processed in parallel

`.mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))` - the comparison in the filter is more intuitive if we convert to `String`, but it's not really needed

`.filter(new StatefulFilter(" "))` - here we filter out any space that comes after another space

`.map(x -> x.equals(" ") ? "!" : x)` - now we can replace the remaining spaces with exclamation marks

`.collect(Collectors.joining(""))` - and finally we can join the characters together to reconstitute a `String`

The `StatefulFilter` itself is pretty straight forward - it checks whether a) we have a previous character at all, b) whether the previous character is the same as the current character and c) whether the current character is the delimiter (space). It returns `false` (meaning the character gets deleted) only if all a, b and c are true.